# buttons in multiple lines - Flutter

Tags: flutter, listview, filter, row, flutter-dependencies

I want to list text button in the way represented in "Booking APP" filter

[image]

I've tried a Row, ListView and GridView, i want something like a row in multiple line.

the code

```
 SingleChildScrollView(
                padding: FxSpacing.x(24),
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                child: Row(
                    children:
                        ['Any', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5'].map((element) {
                  return InkWell(
                      onTap: () {
                        setState(() {
                          if (estateHomeController.selectedBathRooms.contains(element)) {
                            estateHomeController.selectedBathRooms.remove(element);
                          } else {
                            estateHomeController.selectedBathRooms.add(element);
                          }
                        });
                      },
                      child: SingleBath(
                        bath: element,
                        selected: estateHomeController.selectedBathRooms.contains(element),
                      ));
                }).toList()),
              ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `Wrap` widget

```
     Wrap(
        children: ['Any', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
            .map(
              (e) => InkWell(
                      onTap: () {
                        setState(() {
                          if (estateHomeController.selectedBathRooms.contains(element)) {
                            estateHomeController.selectedBathRooms.remove(element);
                          } else {
                            estateHomeController.selectedBathRooms.add(element);
                          }
                        });
                      },
                      child: SingleBath(
                        bath: element,
                        selected: estateHomeController.selectedBathRooms.contains(element),
                      )),
            )
            .toList(),
        spacing: 8,
        runSpacing: 8,
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Material chips might also suit your use case since you are looking at using these chips as filters to show different results